# GET - 404 (Not Found) Error when fetching json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch

Here is the snippet of my fetch json file. There is always an error when I try to fetch the json file data.

```
const onSearchSubmit = (term) => {
    console.log(term);
    fetch('./JSONDATA.json', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            setFruits(data);
            console.log(data.term);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error + "json file");
        });
};
```

[ORIGINAL SNIPPET IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvIbB.png)

Comment: does the url, localhost:3000/JSONDATA.json exist?

Comment: open this path in your browser and see the result. Is your JSON available

Comment: I think yes it is available. I have http://localhost:3000/ . Every time I type in http://localhost:3000/JSONDATA.json I always routed to my project I can see the whole project on the browser. But on my console browser it has an error 404.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to `React` nor to `fetch()`. It says your server has responded with `404 Not Found`. This means your file is not present / not reachable.

*Verify with the browser (or `curl`) that url `http://localhost:3000/JSONDATA.json` exists and is reachable*

#### Side note

`'Content-Type': 'application/json'` is not required, this is the request `body` type header, but you do not have body.

Comment: I type this http://localhost:3000/JSONDATA.json and I always routed to my project but on the console browser says error 404.  and I also import my JSONDATA.json file  import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
import JSONDATA from "./JSONDATA.json";

Comment: @Corona "I always routed to my project" means you see no file?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I removed the headers with "Content-Type": "application/json" . On my Network says OK 200 however, on my console browser says.   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0json file

Comment: ` [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "fruit": "Lime",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Lime_-_whole_and_halved.jpg",
    "description": "In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo."
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "fruit": "Pineberry",
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Pineberries.jpg",
    "description": "In sagittis dui vel nisl. Duis ac nibh. Fusce lacus purus, aliquet at, feugiat non, pretium quis, lectus."
  }]  `     Here is my json file